# understanding a function object

Tags: javascript

In javascript a function is an object.

Is the function's definition recorded in `[[FunctionLocation]]` ?

Therefore it is not stored directly in the object but by reference to it's location in the source.
Is this correct ?

[image]

Comment: That is an example of how a debugger might show a function. It does not tell anything about how it is implemented at the source code processing level, and arguably you should not be concerned with that. You don't get to analyze other functions' source code at runtime in Javascript anyway, so it should not bother you where and if their source code is stored after it was parsed. That FunctionLocation is for your convenience so that *you* know where to look for the source code.

Comment: This is implementation-dependent. But I guess most engines store some kind of compiled code instead of just the location of the JS source.

Comment: To retrieve the source code of the function use: `foo.toString()`.